# Angular JS routing with templateUrl

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angularjs, routes

I have the following route config

```
  .state('employee', {
                    url: '/employee',
                            templateUrl: '/Home/EmployeePartialViews/ListEmployee.html',
                            controller: 'employeeController',
                            controllerAs: 'viewModel'
                    })
```

But it gives me the following error:

> angular.js:11756 GET
>   http://localhost:64956/Home/EmployeePartialViews/ListEmployee.html 404
>   (Not Found)

What can i do ? please someone help me :)

Comment: Click on the link that you just created in yellow block above? does it open in browser? probably not. Path is either incorrect or you haven't configured server routing properly. We don't know enough about your backend setup to know which. 404 status is sent by server

Comment: I am using web api , routes are like     localhost:64956/api/employees    , and it returns a json  , until here everything perfect  , but i don't know if i point like this to a view it should render it ?  i mean if path is ok  ,how can         localhost:64956//Home/EmployeePartialViews/ListEmployee.html should work? @charlietfl

Comment: Same way you would output any other html file. I don't do any work with .Net so am not a good one to ask in that regard

Comment: You might want to add your own answer in case it helps others in future unless it was something silly. Curious myself what the issue was